# for loops in R programming

Tags: r, loops

I am a newbie in R programming. i want to solve a problem using R but i am having error. I wish kind people out there can help me to learn something so that i can help someone too.

```
g = 9.8
tt = c(10,15,16)
n = length(tt)
emp =NULL

for(i in n){
emp[i] = tt[i]*4
print(emp)
}
```

After running this code in R, i got reply like below:

```
 > for(i in n){
 + emp[i] = tt[i]*4
 + print(emp)
 + }
[1] NA NA 64
```

Any  ideas about how to remove NA values or solve this problem? any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a sequence to iterate over for your loop to work.  By simply changing `n` to `1:n` it will work.

```
g = 9.8
tt = c(10,15,16)
n = length(tt)
emp =NULL

for(i in 1:n){
  emp[i] = tt[i]*4
  print(emp)
}

[1] 40
[1] 40 60
[1] 40 60 64
```

Comment: Thank You. but i need little more help. i want to see all results in a row like [1] 40 60 64. how can i do that?

Comment: @AliYousuf, right now the values are in a single vector.  You just see each separately because it is printing each time a new element is added.  If you just `print(emp)` again you will have what you want.

Comment: To just get a output like 40 60 64 (which is multiplication of vector tt with 4), you don't need a for loop. Simply assign: emp <- tt*4 and print it.